Adding a pushbutton to new figure in MATLAB
The app below allows me to open a figure with a push button. When I click on the push button, the callback generates a new figure with an imagesc plot on it. I'd like to be able to add another button to the imagesc figure so that I can have a callback that will allow me to save the plot as a png.
This is my code for the app:
function plotApp
fig = uifigure;

fig.Position(3:4) = [300 180];
uibutton(fig, ...
    "Text","Plot Data", ...
    "ButtonPushedFcn", @(src,event) plotButtonPushed);

end

function plotButtonPushed(~)
% get data from workspace
v = evalin('base','data');

imagesc(v(:,:,1));% show image     
roi=drawpolyline; % pick points to create improfile
xy= roi.Position; % get xy data

%cx is the x-coordinate values, c is the sampled pixel intensities
[cx,~,c] = improfile(v,xy(:,1),xy(:,2));
assignin("base","cx",cx);
assignin("base","c",c);
axes('position',[.6 .2 .3 .3]);  % create small window
line(cx,c(:,1,1),'color','r')    % plot red channel
line(cx,c(:,1,2),'color','g')    % plot green channel
line(cx,c(:,1,3),'color','b')    % plot blue channel
end

This is the first figure with the pushbutton:

This is the figure I would like to place the new pushbutton:

How can I add a new push button to the imagesc plot?

The best would be to show the figure as a part of the app window. That is slot some space for the figure widget and activate a push button if the figure is available, through some flag setting. You can then pass the figure handle and retrieve the image out of it and save them in any location you may want to.

You'll need the handle to the new figure and then place the button on it. Could be something like this:
function plotButtonPushed(~)
% get data from workspace
v = evalin('base','data');

newFigHandle = uifigure;    %Create new figure
ax = axes(newFigHandle);    %Create axis on figure 

imgHandle = imagesc(ax, v(:,:,1)); %show image     

%Create new push button
uibutton(newFigHandle, ...
    "Text","Save Plot", ...
    "ButtonPushedFcn", @(src,evt,image) savePlotBushed(src,evt,imgHandle));

roi=drawpolyline; % pick points to create improfile
...

The save plot function could then just look like this:
function savePlotBushed(~,~,imgHandle)
imwrite(uint8(rescale(imgHandle.CData,0,2^8-1)),'C:\test.png')
end

If you want to save not only the image created by imagesc but also the rest in your new figure, I recommend you getframe() or the great export_fig toolbox, free on GitHub.
